# Authenticated Proxies in PhantomJS - Python Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use Authenticated proxies with PhantomJS - Selenium.

Below is my code for Chromedriver and it works fine.
However,
I have never tried using PhantomJS before.
As per the instructions, provided by the Proxy provider, it asks me to add the following line to the code.

> page.customHeaders={'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('USERNAME:PASSWORD')};

Could someone please advise where to add this?

Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
proxies = 'http://us.proxymesh.com:31280'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxies)
b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
b.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
```

Comment: Could you try this `service_args = ['--proxy={}'.format(proxy),'--proxy-type=socks5']` and then `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs.exe', service_args = service_args)`